# Bubble sorting my array does not sort it

Tags: java

I sort an array of chunks by doing this:

```
    for (int i =0; i<this.getQueue().size();i++) {
        for (int j =0; j<this.getQueue().size()-i-1;j++) {
            Chunk temp1 = this.getQueue().get(i);
            Chunk temp2 = this.getQueue().get(i+1);
                if (temp1 != null &&temp2 != null && temp2.getLocation().getY() < temp1.getLocation().getY()) {
                    this.getQueue().set(i, temp2);
                    this.getQueue().set(i+1, temp1);
                }
            }
        }
```

What I want is the the chunks with the lowest Y coordinate will be at the start of the array and the ones with the bigger Y coordinate will be at the end of the array. And this is my result:

```
1024.0
944.0
1104.0
944.0
1104.0
----BEFORE-----
944.0
1024.0
944.0
1104.0
1104.0
---AFTER---
```

Why is this not working It seams fine. I dont want to use a comparator so dont suggest it.

More info,
the Y cords are floats.
I got the result by for each looping on this queue and printed the Y locations.

Comment: The reason you're getting downvotes is probably because there's nothing game-specific about your question. I've flagged it for migration to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), where it should be on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inner loop iterates `j` times correctly, but the indexes you compare do not change within that loop. Therefore it's impossible for any value to bubble more than 1 position along. Instead of `.get(i)` and `.get(i+1)`, you probably need `.get(j)` and `.get(j+1)`.

You can usually debug problems like this with a debugger, or with `System.out.println` statements to show the values of `i` at each step.

Comment: Thanks sorry I was stupid I didn't notice that lol XD

Comment: And its not i+j its just j. i+j doesn't make sense.

Comment: In this case you're right, but i+j would make sense if you were bubbling values in the other direction. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably more efficient to swap once per loop by first making a record of best index to swap. Also start the j loop with i + 1 instead of 0. This makes it easier to understand you are swapping starting 1 above the current index. Untested but should give you an idea of how this could be approached.

```
int qSize = this.getQueue().size();
for (int i = 0; i < qSize; i++) {
        Chunk temp1 = this.getQueue().get(i);
        if (temp1 != null) {
            int bestY = temp1.getLocation().getY();
            int swapWithIndex = -1; 
            for (int j =i + 1; j < qSize; j++) {
                  Chunk temp2 = this.getQueue().get(j);
                  if (temp2 != null && temp2.getLocation().getY() < bestY) {
                      bestY = temp2.getLocation().getY();
                      swapWithIndex = j;
                  }
            }

            if (swapWithIndex != -1) {
                 this.getQueue().set(i, this.getQueue().get(swapWithIndex));
                 this.getQueue().set(swapWithIndex, temp1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```